# Calculating/converting Coterminal angles to show only positive numbers

Tags: matlab, octave, trigonometry, angle

I need a little help calculating/converting coterminal angles to show only the positive angles
I'm using octave/matlab.

Example: 60,-300, and 780 degrees are all coterminal angles (they share a terminal side)
[Coterminal example](http://www.mathwords.com/c/coterminal.htm)

What I'm trying to get is when I do a `mod(-370,-360)` the answer is `-10` which is correct but I'm trying to have the answer come out as a **positive** answer/angle whether the number entered is negative or positive so the answer I would want is `350`.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: That link results in a 404 error...

Comment: Thanks I forgot the htm at the end should work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a positive divisor: `mod(-370, 360)`?

Comment: Thanks I guess I was over thinking it